# PDO Database Class

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

Hello so I am using [this](https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class) PHP PDO Database Class and I'm using the easyCRUD class there. In deleting a data using easyCRUD class this is a sample code:

```
$person->Id  = "17";
$deleted     = $person->Delete();
```

The equivalent of that in sql is this `"DELETE FROM persons WHERE Id = 17 LIMIT 1"` and my problem is what if I want to delete a data and run a sql like this?

```
"DELETE FROM persons WHERE Username='Robert' AND Email='email@gmail.com'"
```

How can I run it using that class? Thank you.

Comment: Why not check out doctrine http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just update the attribute and call save().

```
$person->id  = "16";
$deleted     = $person->save();
```

Comment: The library you are using doesn't support searching like that. It would seem you can only search by ID. I suggest that you take a look at a different library, such as doctrine that @abhik-chakraborty has already mentioned.